# Delay enter transition animation in Angular 4.x

Tags: angular, animation

I have applied animation on `<tr *ngFor='let something of Something' [@rowAnimate]> ...</tr>`

Here is my code to animate rows

```
animations: [
    trigger("rowAnimate", [
        transition("void=>*", [
            animate("500ms ease-in-out", keyframes([
                style({ transform: 'translateX(+200%)'}),   
                style({ transform: 'translateX(+150%)'}),
                style({ transform: 'translateX(+100%)'}),
                style({ transform: 'translateX(+50%)'}),
                style({ transform: 'translateX(0%)'})
            ]))
        ]),
        transition("*=>void", [
            animate("2000ms ease-in-out", style({ left: 100, opacity: 0.0, }))
        ])

    ])
]
```

Its working but not same as i want . What i want is to delay each row animation by some time(i.e first row 1 animation start then row 2 and so on).

I don't want animation to run concurrently for each row

Comment: for each row you should write the same again or better with `ngFor`.

Answer (score 2):

Use [query](https://angular.io/api/animations/query) and [stagger](https://angular.io/api/animations/stagger). Also put animation trigger on table, so you can select rows in your query:

```
trigger("slide", [
  transition("* => slideIn", [
    // First hide the rows
    query('.row ', style({ opacity: 0, transform: "translateY(-40px)" })),
    // Then slide in one by one using stagger. Here first timing parameter i.e. 100ms is the delay you seek
    query('.row', stagger('100ms',
      animate('500ms', keyframes([
        style({opacity: 0, transform: 'translateY(-40px)', offset: 0}),
        style({opacity: 0.25, transform: 'translateY(-25px)', offset: 0.25}),
        style({opacity: 0.5, transform: 'translateY(-5px)', offset: 0.5}),
        style({opacity: 0.75, transform: 'translateY(5px)', offset: 0.75}),
        style({opacity: 1, transform: 'translateY(0)', offset: 1.0})
      ]))
    ))
  ])
])
```

Use special selectors like `:enter` or `:leave` in your query if the rows are being added/removed dynamically. More special selectors in query page.

Comment: Too late for the answers, `angular 4.2` released later and solved my problem. Anyway, Thanks for the response.